# Построение пути в ларавел

Tags: php, laravel

Есть главная страница, и там должна быть кнопка 'Профиль', также есть разные роли пользователей,
и у каждого пользователя свой name() - роута, пример:

`Routes.php:`

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:approver',
    'namespace' => 'Approver'], function(){

    // главная страница панели
    Route::get('/approver/panel', 'MainController@index')
        ->name('approver.panel');

});


/**
 * Админ-панель Волонтера
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:volounter',
    'namespace' => 'Volounter'], function(){

    // главная страница панели
    Route::get('/volounter/panel', 'MainController@index')
        ->name('volounter.panel');

});


/**
 * Админ-панель Пользователя
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:user',
    'namespace' => 'User',], function(){

    // главная страница панели
    Route::get('/user', 'MainController@index')
        ->name('user.panel');

});
```

У каждого пользователь есть роль и зависимости от роля, выполняется роут, и для этого маршрута есть name().

Вопрос таков: у меня стоит вот так, как можно упростить этот код?

```
            @if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() == false)
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary mr-4" href="#">Вход</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="#">Регистрация</a>
            @else
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" href="
                        @role('user')
                            {{ route('wiki.user.panel') }}
                        @endrole

                        @role('approver')
                            {{ route('wiki.approver.panel') }}
                        @endrole

                        @role('volounter')
                            {{ route('wiki.volounter.panel') }}
                        @endrole

                        @role('historian')
                            {{ route('wiki.historian.panel') }}
                        @endrole

                         @role('super_admin')
                            {{ route('wiki.admin.index') }}
                        @endrole

                        ">Панелька</a>
            @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос был решен, вот таким способом:

`{{ route("wiki." . \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()->getRoleNames()->first() . ".panel") }}`

Просто берем текущего пользователя, и имя его роля, и подставляем, для меня этого хватило т.к мои пути назывались с именами ролей